# Can I save the results of a loop into a list (Python)?

Tags: python, list, loops

I created a loop that was supposed to count from 0.00000000 up to a variable number by increments of 0.00400000. The loop works okay (doesn't start at zero), but I can't save the loop into a list. I want to plot this loop (my time loop) against another list that I have (current) to show how the current changes as a function of time.

The main problem is that I can't save my time into a list, and that list needs to be the same length as the current list.

I have tried making the loop, but don't know how to save the iterations into a list to plot later.

```
import numpy as np

N, v1, v2 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\laure\OneDrive\Documents\DropData\Drop4Data(Complete)1MMod.txt', unpack = True)



#Calculate Current from Voltage Drop
V= [v1[i] -v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))]

R= 1000000

I= [V[i] / R for i in range (len(V))]

Loop= len(I)*0.004
T=0
while T <= Loop:
   T+= 0.00400000
```

If I print just T, then it works out fine and prints the values in different lines.

When I try to use T as an axis value in graphing it tells me that "x and y must be the same length". When I try to see how long T is, it says "object of type 'float' has no len()"

Answer (score 0):

Simple as having an array to store the variable each time you increment it.

```
import numpy as np

N, v1, v2 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\laure\OneDrive\Documents\DropData\Drop4Data(Complete)1MMod.txt', unpack = True)



#Calculate Current from Voltage Drop
V= [v1[i] -v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))]

R= 1000000

I= [V[i] / R for i in range (len(V))]

Loop= len(I)*0.004
T=0
x_steps = []
while T <= Loop:
   x_steps.append(T) # append the current number to the array
   T+= 0.00400000
```

However a better way to do this is do a `np.linspace` call:

```
np.linspace(0,len(I)*.004, 0.004)
```

Comment: @JETM proper use of linspace or is it up to n-1?

Comment: I don't know off-hand

Answer (score 0):

You could make two list, one that stores the index, and one that stores the T value. Then you can use the two list to plot the values.

```
import numpy as np

N, v1, v2 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\laure\OneDrive\Documents\DropData\Drop4Data(Complete)1MMod.txt', unpack = True)



#Calculate Current from Voltage Drop
V= [v1[i] -v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))]

R= 1000000

I= [V[i] / R for i in range (len(V))]

Loop= len(I)*0.004
T=0
i = 0
T_list = []
axis_list = []
while T <= Loop:
   T+= 0.00400000
   T_list.append(T)
   axis_list.append(i) 
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seemed to work best for me.